# querySelector и regex

Tags: javascript, html, регулярные-выражения

Добрый День. Нужно решить следующую задачу. Найти все email адреса на любой странице и изменить им цвет. То есть адрес может быть как ссылкой, так и просто частью какого либо текста. Как пример можно привести HTML mail.ru, где email адрес находится рядом с "входящими" или возле выхода. Проблема в том, что бы найти такие адреса на странице. Функция с валидацией адреса есть

```
    function checkEmailValidate (emailAddress) {
      const regexEmail = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
      regexEmail.test(emailAddress)
    }
```

Comment: Вместо отсылки к mail.ru, приведите пример исходного HTML-кода и ожидаемый результат, а также опишите, что не работает в вашем коде.

Comment: Кстати, функция пропускает неверные адреса (например, `....@mail.ru`) и не пропускает верные (`my+test@mail.ru`, `вася@яндекс.рф`, `"целое предложение с пробелами"."not necessarily in Russian"@example.org`, `user@localhost` и пр.)

Comment: http://emailregex.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Рабочий код:

```js
var replaced = $("#content").html().replace( /(?![^<]+>)([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+\@[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/g,'<span class="red">$1</span>');
$("#content").html(replaced);
```

```css
.red{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
Текст внутри тега a <a href="mailto:info@mail.ru">info@mail.ru</a><br>
Просто адрес, написанный в тексте info@mail.ru 1
</div>
```

## Объяснение:

`html()` - получаем текст страницы вместе с тегами.

`(?![^<]+>)` - проверяем, чтобы адрес не был внутри тега, например  `href="mailto:info@mail.ru"`.

`^` и `$` - в начале и в конце нужно убрать, эти символы означают начало и конец строки

`g` - все вхождения

Comment: Именно то, что нужно. Спасибо